# DB2 luw performamce issues

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am looking into performance issues with one of our database. The database1 is extremely slow compared to database2 - a copy of database 1 in different server . On looking further, I see the production database is not using the memory allocated. The database memory, sort heap, shared sort heap threshold are really low.

Database version is v10.5

```
database 1
(INSTANCE_MEMORY) = AUTOMATIC(5487480)  
(SELF_TUNING_MEM) = ON
(DATABASE_MEMORY) = AUTOMATIC(248622)
(SHEAPTHRES_SHR) = AUTOMATIC(5001)
(SORTHEAP) = AUTOMATIC(1000)
(DBHEAP) = AUTOMATIC(4401)    

database 2
(INSTANCE_MEMORY) = AUTOMATIC(3835692)
(SELF_TUNING_MEM) = ON
(DATABASE_MEMORY) = AUTOMATIC(860764)
(SHEAPTHRES_SHR) = AUTOMATIC(506165)
(SORTHEAP) = AUTOMATIC(50000)
(DBHEAP) = AUTOMATIC(4401)
```

I am trying to run some MQT refresh on both databases, database2 completes within 2-3hr. But database1 takes 7-8 hr. Can anyone help with how I can make the database use more memory?

Answer (score 0):

`AUTOCONFIGURE` can be a reasonable place to start, but if this is a production database do be carefull

Still, you can try `AUTOCONFIGURE APPLY NONE` and see what it recommends.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008960.html

Comment: I ran autoconfigure and the only thing different is the bufferpool sizes. I tried making them automatic, but not a big difference ! :(